# Jquery Mobile - Several items from listview on same line

Tags: list, jquery-mobile, grid, line

I am encountering an issue with Jquery Mobile :

I want to display a grid of items using three columns. Each new item must be displayed next to the previous one and begin a new line after the third column.

To give you an example, I want something like this : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BMA3Y/)

But my items have to be items from a splitButtonList (an icon with labels on the left and a clickable button on the right) instead of the blocks from the previous example.

The problem is : when I use the kind of code shown below, each new item is display at the bottom of the previous one, like in a list. I cannot manage to display it using my three columns grid pattern [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e2uaU/72/).

```
<body>
    <div data-role="page" data-theme="c" id="projets">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="f" data-tap-toggle="false" id="banniere">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="content">
        <div class="ui-grid-b">        
            <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="star" data-split-theme="a" class="listview">
                <li>
                    <a href="projects.html">
                        <img src="img/icon/file.png" />
                        <h3>A label</h3>
                        <p>Another one</p>
                        <p>And finally another one</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="index.html">Plop</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="projects.html">
                        <img src="img/icon/file.png" />
                        <h3>A label</h3>
                        <p>Another one</p>
                        <p>And finally another one</p>
                    </a>
                    <a href="index.html">Plop</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /grid-b -->
    </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="f" data-tap-toggle="false" id="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Do you have any idea of what to do ? Using CSS maybe ? Any clue would be very precious for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZcK5/1/)

You were basically missing the 3 child containers of the grid:

```
<div class="ui-grid-b">
    <div class="ui-block-a">Listview 1 goes here...</div>
    <div class="ui-block-b">Listview 2 goes here...</div>
    <div class="ui-block-c">Listview 3 goes here...</div>
</div><!-- /grid-b -->
```

So, as you can see you will need three different listview.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I was looking for ! I am afraid I did not properly understood the behavior of a ui-grid...